# Trouble with if/raise SyntaxError and ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I am having trouble because when I enter a get parameter it takes me to the correct city name but it displays my SyntaxError also, but I want the SyntaxError to just be displayed when a city name is misspelled or not within the attribute table. Any help?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping
#set workspace
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
#set the dataframe
fc = ("N:\Lab13\cities.shp")
cities = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Cities")[0]
cities.showLabels = True
def cityname():
    cityName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

    cities_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "cities_lyr")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(cities, "NEW_SELECTION", "CITY_NAME = '{}' ".format(cityName))

    arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0].zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.Delete_management("cities_lyr")
    if cityName != "CITY_NAME":
        raise SyntaxError("Check your spelling or whether it is a European city.")
    arcpy.AddMessage("You zoomed in to " + str(cityName))
try:
    cityname()
except SyntaxError as se:
    arcpy.AddError("There was an error. " + str(se))
```

Comment: is your city called "CITY_NAME"?  Because that's why your syntax check is asking.  `if 'New York' != 'CITY_NAME' then...` - you need to do a lookup to find all the values from CITY_NAME and then test your `cityName` against that lookup

Comment: `SyntaxError` is an inappropriate exception type here. It is used for syntax errors in *Python code*. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SyntaxError). You should probably define a custom exception type, since you are expecting it and handling it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your city called "CITY_NAME"? Because that's why your syntax check is asking. if 'New York' != 'CITY_NAME' then... - you need to do a lookup to find all the values from CITY_NAME and then test your cityName against that lookup.

You could do this a couple of ways - Quickest might be to just check if any city has been selected by your `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management`

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(cities)

if len(desc.FIDSet) == 0:
    raise SyntaxError("Check your spelling or whether it is a European city.")
```

Use the code above to replace your `if` check from your code

```
if cityName != "CITY_NAME":
    raise SyntaxError("Check your spelling or whether it is a European city.")
```

Comment: The user puts the city name they want to zoom to in the GetParameter(0) and then it zooms to this city. CITY_NAME is the attribute in the table that lists all the city names. I am still unsure of what to put, so it raises an error for misspelled names or incorrect ones. I do not think the the CITY_NAME is correct

Comment: This is the error i got:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\E\Documents\PYTHONCLASS\13\gscript.py", line 24, in <module> cityname()
  File "C:\Users\E\Documents\PYTHONCLASS\13\gscript.py", line 19, in cityname
    desc = arcpy.Describe(cities_layer)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1246, in Describe
    return gp.describe(value)

Comment: File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 374, in describe
    self._gp.Describe(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
IOError: "cities_lyr" does not exist

Comment: Ah I see the problem - you select on `cities` so do a Describe on `cities`.  I've updated my code.

Comment: you can probably remove `cities_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "cities_lyr")` and `arcpy.Delete_management("cities_lyr")` from your code, it doesn't appear to be used

Answer (score 5):

First, if you are raising Exceptions, consider using the `ValueError` or `NameError`, as a misspelling of a city is not a "syntax error".

That being said, it looks like you have a logical error in your code.  You are raising the first SyntaxError if the user input does not equal the literal string of `"CITY_NAME"`.  Therefore, this tool will always fail unless the user inputs `"CITY_NAME"`, and at that point, I'm assuming you do not actually have a city in your database where the `"CITY_NAME" = 'CITY_NAME'` query would return any results...

You would be better off checking if the user input is a valid value within the table.